# Url open encoding

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-unicode

I have the following code for urllib and BeautifulSoup:

```
getSite = urllib.urlopen(pageName) # open current site   
getSitesoup = BeautifulSoup(getSite.read()) # reading the site content 
print getSitesoup.originalEncoding
for value in getSitesoup.find_all('link'): # extract all <a> tags 
    defLinks.append(value.get('href'))
```

The result of it:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py:231: UnicodeWarning: Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
  "Some characters could not be decoded, and were "
```

And when i try to read the site i get:

```
�7�e����0*"I߷�G�H����F������9-������;��E�YÞBs���������㔶?�4i���)�����^W�����`w�Ke��%��*9�.'OQB���V��@�����]���(P��^��q�$�S5���tT*�Z
```

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup works with Unicode internally; it'll try and decode non-unicode responses from UTF-8 by default.

It looks like the site you are trying to load is using a different encode; for example, it *could* be UTF-16 instead:

```
>>> print u"""�7�e����0*"I߷�G�H����F������9-������;��E�YÞBs���������㔶?�4i���)�����^W�����`w�Ke��%��*9�.'OQB���V��@�����]���(P��^��q�$�S5���tT*�Z""".encode('utf-8').decode('utf-16-le')
뿯㞽뿯施뿯붿뿯붿⨰䤢럟뿯䞽뿯䢽뿯붿뿯붿붿뿯붿뿯붿뿯㦽붿뿯붿뿯붿뿯㮽뿯붿붿썙䊞붿뿯붿뿯붿뿯붿뿯붿铣㾶뿯㒽붿뿯붿붿뿯붿뿯붿坞뿯붿뿯붿뿯悽붿敋뿯붿붿뿯⪽붿✮兏붿뿯붿붿뿯䂽뿯붿뿯붿뿯嶽뿯붿뿯⢽붿뿯庽뿯붿붿붿㕓뿯붿뿯璽⩔뿯媽
```

It could be `mac_cyrillic` too:

```
>>> print u"""�7�e����0*"I߷�G�H����F������9-������;��E�YÞBs���������㔶?�4i���)�����^W�����`w�Ke��%��*9�.'OQB���V��@�����]���(P��^��q�$�S5���tT*�Z""".encode('utf-8').decode('mac_cyrillic')
пњљ7пњљeпњљпњљпњљпњљ0*"IяЈпњљGпњљHпњљпњљпњљпњљFпњљпњљпњљпњљпњљпњљ9-пњљпњљпњљпњљпњљпњљ;пњљпњљEпњљY√ЮBsпњљпњљпњљпњљпњљпњљпњљпњљпњљгФґ?пњљ4iпњљпњљпњљ)пњљпњљпњљпњљпњљ^Wпњљпњљпњљпњљпњљ`wпњљKeпњљпњљ%пњљпњљ*9пњљ.'OQBпњљпњљпњљVпњљпњљ@пњљпњљпњљпњљпњљ]пњљпњљпњљ(Pпњљпњљ^пњљпњљqпњљ$пњљS5пњљпњљпњљtT*пњљZ
```

But I have way too little information about what kind of site you are trying to load nor can I read the output of either encoding. :-)

You'll need to decode the result of `getSite()` before passing it to BeautifulSoup:

```
getSite = urllib.urlopen(pageName).decode('utf-16')
```

Generally, the website will return what encoding was used in the headers, in the form of a `Content-Type` header (probably `text/html; charset=utf-16` or similar).

Comment: the site has charset=utf-8", and also tried with decode('utf-16') and i got decoding error.

Comment: Can you share a link? You may have to guess the encoding as it could be the site is misconfigured.

Answer (score 2):

The page is in UTF-8, but the server is sending it to you in a compressed format:

```
>>> print getSite.headers['content-encoding']
gzip
```

You'll need to decompress the data before running it through Beautiful Soup. I got an error using zlib.decompress() on the data, but writing the data to a file and using gzip.open() to read from it worked fine--I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and as Leonard mentioned, it was due to a compressed format.

[This](http://love-python.blogspot.be/2008/07/accept-encoding-gzip-to-make-your.html) link solved it for me which says to add `('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate')` in the request header. For example:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('Referer', referer),
('User-Agent', uagent),
('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate')]
usock = opener.open(url)
url = usock.geturl()
data = decode(usock)
usock.close() 
return data
```

Where the `decode()` function is defined by:

```
def decode (page):
    encoding = page.info().get("Content-Encoding")    
    if encoding in ('gzip', 'x-gzip', 'deflate'):
        content = page.read()
        if encoding == 'deflate':
            data = StringIO.StringIO(zlib.decompress(content))
        else:
            data = gzip.GzipFile('', 'rb', 9, StringIO.StringIO(content))
        page = data.read()

    return page
```